# Custom counter VueJS

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm new  to VueJS and I'm facing a problem when trying to create a custom counter. This is the code

```
<template v-for="(ben, i) in plan.beneficios">
   <div class="w-80 w-90-480 m-auto pa-hor-5-480"
      :class="((customCounter++)%2 == 0) ? 'show':'not_show'">
```

The problem is that when I put the instruction customCounter++ the page never loads, it's like Vue keeps incrementing the variable forever. Also, I can't use the variable i because the Json I get is not well formated.

Thank you so much for your help.

The data format looks like this:

```
"beneficios": {
    "b1": { .. },
    "b2": { ... },
    "b3": { ... }
}
```

And the variable is created like this:

```
data: function() {
    return {
        planes1: null,
        planes2: null,
        config: null,
        customCounter : 0
    }
}
```

Comment: `i` is reliable, no? If not, you can bracket 3 params in a v-for, like this: `v-for=(item, key, index) in variable`

Comment: Please provide a [mre].  What  is the structure/data of `plan.beneficios`? Where is `customCounter` defined?

Comment: i is not reliable because the json file looks like this:
beneficios:{
 b1:{ ... },
 b2:{ ... },
 b3:{ ... }
}
So the i variable is printing "b1", "b2", ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `:class` binding changes `customerCounter` value, and is re-evaluated each time `customCounter` is changed. So your bindings trigger a loop, and all `:class` bindings will be bound to the same `customerCounter` value.

As [@Lewis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5312731/lewis) suggested, use the index. You can use `Object.values` (or `Object.entries`) to transform an object to an array.

```html
<template v-for="(ben, i) in Object.values(plan.beneficios)">
   <div class="w-80 w-90-480 m-auto pa-hor-5-480"
      :class="i % 2 == 0 ? 'show' : 'not_show'">
```